# Show presenter notes in LibreOffice Impress without a second monitor

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, libreoffice

I am using LibreOffice impress for my presentations and I want to get the presentation notes displayed at rehearsal time without plugging in a second monitor. I checked everywhere, but I could not find any solution to get the presenter notes.

Comment: What do you mean by presenter notes?

Comment: Presenter notes means the additional facts that we include in the slides. But they are not visible for the audience but only for the presenter. Those notes give presenters huge help for the presentation.

Comment: I can't find this feature either. It looks like you will need to contact LibreOffice and ask them to implement it.

Comment: @user68186 I think that must be done.

Comment: Please file a feature request at https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/

Comment: @user68186 do I need to report it as a bug or a new feature?

Comment: Feature requests and bugs are to be reported through the same system. I think it is a feature request, the admins will change the label if needed.

Comment: @user68186 got it. reported.

Comment: I think there is a makro which can do this for you:
[https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/64534/feature-request-add-show-presenter-view-in-impress/](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/64534/feature-request-add-show-presenter-view-in-impress/)

Answer (score 3):

Select View / Notes from the menu.

It shows a format with the slide at the top of the page and the notes below it. Not beautiful but OK for practice on a single screen.

[image]

Comment: This is fine. The problem is with Menu: **Slide Show > Rehearse Timing**. OP wants to see the notes while rehearsing with only one display, namely just the laptop not connected to any projector or a second screen.

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't clear to me from the question that OP wanted the timing.  I can't think of a way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

This **feature is not yet developed** in the Libre Impress. I have already reported the issue. From following link, you can view the **feature request to bugzilla**.
https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=122493

Answer (score 1):

You can set the presenter console to be always on by changing the following setting:  Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Advanced, then select 'Expert Configuration', enter 'StartAlways' into the search bar and toggle the setting to 'True'.

Comment: This works just fine. Thanks.